# Matlab: Prepend string to a cell array of strings

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array, prepend

I want to prepend a string in a cell array of strings. For example, if I've:

```
q = {'1', '2'};
p = '3';
```

I want to do something like that

```
a = prepend(q, p);
a =
   '3'  '1'  '2'
```

How can I prepend a string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a cell array of `char`, not strings.
[`string` and `char`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html) mean different things since the release of R2016b. You can prepend a char array to a cell array in the same way how [cell arrays are combined](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combine-cell-arrays.html).

```
a=[p,q] ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍
```

---

In the similar way, you can also combine a cell array of char with a string array or a simple char array with a string array which will result in a string array though. The datatype can be changed later to a cell array of char if required using [`cellstr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I'm using the R2014a release, so I don't have strings yet...